# Multiple REST API requests using PLinq

Tags: c#, plinq

I'm trying to clean this up so experts can help me move forward.

as "svik" suggested below, after all the tasks are completed, I have a `HTTPResponseMessage[]`.

How do I know what response was for what request?

```
var tasks = File.ReadLines(filepath).Select(url => client.GetAsync(url));
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLINQ doesn't work well with asynchronous operations. But you don't actually need PLINQ here:

```
var tasks = File.ReadLines(filepath).Select(url => client.GetAsync(url));
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This will *start* all the tasks serially, but they then continue to run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, where do i handle the response the response is a JSON containing Location information ( url(s) ) of the documents. I need to then do a GET REST call on each url and save the documents to the folder

Comment: Also, when the tasks complete, how do i co-related the "Responses" back to the corresponding Folder? I just receive a dump of all Responses. Now, there is no way to figure which response is to which request/folder.

Comment: @billboard You can look at the response's `RequestMessage.RequestUri` to get what the original url was.

Comment: RequestMessage.RequestUri just hold the BaseAddress, the JSON request was sent as a payload. How to get the payload from RequestMessage?

Comment: @Asad, I get the following exception when I try to access the RequestMessage {"Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1[[JasonApiClient.RequestMessage, JasonApiClient, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'."}